# How to only load table view after search?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am looking to create a view controller that has a way for a user to search for devices and then after they click the search button, I want the table view below to be populated. The problem is the tableview is loading right as the view controller is loaded and since the user has not searched for anything yet, the app crashes since theres no data being populated in the table. I want the tableview to not load until the user clicks the search button.

So far I have the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.deviceName.text = deviceArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
```

How do I get this to not load until user clicks the search button first?

Comment: Put your tableView without datasource and add set the datasource when you need to

Comment: what's the syntax to add datasource within a button call?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: All you have to do is to make sure that deviceArray has no elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interface builder don't link your `tableView.dataSource` as `self`, and then in the action of your search button use this code after your search logic

```
 self.tableView.dataSource = self
 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

I hope this helps you, best regards

Comment: "In the interface builder don't link your tableView.dataSource as self"  Huh!?

Comment: I mean don't link datasource in the table, of course in the interface builder code can't be writed

Comment: All he or she has to do is to make sure that the array is empty at startup.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check your datasource in func

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return deviceArray.count
}
```

You should init `deviceArray` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
deviceArray = [];
```

If you didn't search, `deviceArray` will have `count = 0` so that no more cell will be load